# Controller returns page instead of pushing content in the database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to put data from an insert field into the MySQL database with Laravel.
But I run into the problem when I send the form data. The only thing that happens is that the input view is returning.

I have created a show controller

```
namespace pianoCRM\Http\Controllers\Shop;

use DB;
use pianoCRM\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ShopsController extends Controller
{
    // overview alle webwinkels
    public function overview()
    {

        $webshops = DB::table('webshops')->get();

        return view('Shops/ShopsOverview', ['webshops' => $webshops]);

    }
    // Laat input boxen zien
    public function inputview()
    {

        return view('Shops/Shopsinput');

    }

    // Maak Shop aan
    public function create()
    {

        $Shop = new Shop;
        $Shop->Shopname = Input::get('Shopname');
        $Shop->ShopOwner = Input::get('ShopOwner');
        $Shop->Shopmail = Input::get('Shopmail');
        $Shop->Shopkey = Input::get('Shopkey');
        $Shop->Shopsecret = Input::get('Shopsecret');

        $Shop->save();
        exit();

    }
}
```

That use to get data from my input view

```
<form methode="post" action="/piano_crm/public/shops/input" >
    <!-- Webwinkel naam -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Shopname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Webwinkel naam</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Webwinkel Naam">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Webwinkel eigenaar -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="ShopOwner" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Webwinkel eigenaar</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Webwinkel eigenaar">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Webwinkel email -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Shopmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Webwinkel email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Webwinkel email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Shop comsumer key -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Shopkey" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Woocommerce Comsumer key</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Woocommerce Comsumer key">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Shop comsumer secret -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Shopsecret" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Woocommerce Comsumer secret</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Woocommerce Comsumer secret">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my web.php I have created a post route that should to the post controller

```
Route::get('shops/input', 'Shop\ShopsController@inputview')->middleware('auth');
// Een overzicht van alle rapporten die uit gedraaid kunnen worden
Route::post('shops/input', array('uses'=>'Shop\ShopsController@create'))->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: remove   `exit();` function in controller code and add @csrf token in post method

Comment: Missing the CSRF token? Add `@csrf` in your form. You also might want to read about [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) with basic CRUD methods.

Answer (score 1):

On the function create() you call

```
$Shop = new Shop;
```

but on the top of the file you miss to import the Model class placed in "app/models/{ClassName}" folder.

On the folder "app/models/" you need to create one file with this name Shop
and past this code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model
{

    protected $table = '{your table name if is name of table on database is different from the name of class plus "s" if the table name is shops you can remove this variable}';
    protected $id = '{your id field if name is different from id if you have id field you can remove this variable}';
    protected $primaryKey = 'your primaryKey if name is different from id if primary key is id you can remove this variable';


}
```

After on the top of ShopsController file

```
use App\Models\Shop ;
```

Comment: What model do you need to call?

Answer (score 0):

add csrf token in form by using helper function

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

otherwise add url in `verifyCsrfToken.php` file and remove `exit()` function in controller

import model on controller

```
use App\Shop;
```

Comment: I have done this, but the result is the same. 
`<form methode="POST" action="/piano_crm/public/shops/input" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="zfPCsYdwnNp5JVDxoPRFl8nBQc103HNtyCa6GfVs"> `

Comment: I get it back as an _GET instead of a POST. It is returning to `public/shops/input?_token=zfPCsYdwnNp5JVDxoPRFl8nBQc103HNtyCa6GfVs`